# Amazon API generating a request signature in C# .NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, amazon-web-services, c#-4.0

I'm trying to figure out how to pass a parameter in my .NET application. The URL request looks like:

```
http://webservices.amazon.com/onca/xml?
  Service=AWSECommerceService
  &Operation=ItemLookup
  &ResponseGroup=Large
  &SearchIndex=All
  &IdType=UPC
  &ItemId=635753490879
  &AWSAccessKeyId=[Your_AWSAccessKeyID]
  &AssociateTag=[Your_AssociateTag]
  &Timestamp=[YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ssZ]
  &Signature=[Request_Signature]
```

The part that I'm confused about are these:

```
 &Timestamp=[YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ssZ]
      &Signature=[Request_Signature]
```

I'm not sure whether I can Just simply do it something like this for timestamp part:

```
var TimeStamp  = DateTime.Now; // without any special datetime formating?
```

So my question is how do I actually generate this signature URL in the request URL ?

I have all of these parameters above but I'm not sure how to generate this last one ?

Can someone help me out ?

Comment: Anyone guys ?? Any tips ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

AWS utilizes HMAC request-signing. Generally speaking, the way this works is that you create a "message", which is composed of things like your access key(s), request headers, request body and a timestamp. You then HMAC this "message" and that becomes your "signature" for the request. This prevents replay-attacks as each request must have a unique signature.

It looks like the timestamp simply needs to be in ISO format (`YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ssZ`), so, no you can't just use `DateTime.Now`. The default format utilized by `ToString` will not be ISO. Instead, you'd need to use something like:

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:sszzz");
```

Or it would actually probably be better to use UTC time and simply append a `Z`:

```
DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ssZ");
```

As for creating the signature, see the [AWS documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/signature-v4-examples.html#signature-v4-examples-dotnet), where they provide some sample code:

```
static byte[] HmacSHA256(String data, byte[] key)
{
    String algorithm = "HmacSHA256";
    KeyedHashAlgorithm kha = KeyedHashAlgorithm.Create(algorithm);
    kha.Key = key;

    return kha.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data));
}

static byte[] getSignatureKey(String key, String dateStamp, String regionName, String serviceName)
{
    byte[] kSecret = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(("AWS4" + key).ToCharArray());
    byte[] kDate = HmacSHA256(dateStamp, kSecret);
    byte[] kRegion = HmacSHA256(regionName, kDate);
    byte[] kService = HmacSHA256(serviceName, kRegion);
    byte[] kSigning = HmacSHA256("aws4_request", kService);

    return kSigning;
}
```

Comment: Chris wow thanks a lot!!! I found this piece of code but I'm still confused on the "RegionName" and "ServiceName" part for the parameters, what do I need to put in that part??

Comment: That's AWS specific stuff, but I believe they're referring to your region, as cloud services like AWS are generally region-specific (`east-us-1`). Whatever you're on is what would go there. The service is likely the specific AWS service you're making a request to (e.g. `iam`)

Comment: Amazing Chriss thanks a lot !! What about the  dateStamp passed into the getSignatureMethod, does it requires to be passed in the same format as timestamp (yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ssZ) ?

Comment: Yes. ISO dates are pretty much necessary with any type of data interchange. It's called ISO because it's the standard format from the International Standards Organization and is pretty much the only universally understandable date format.

Comment: Thanks! =) If you want you can include this in the reply itself for future readers. Other than that,  this is one of the most complete answers I ever got ! :)

Comment: Chris, what do I do with the signature key in byte[] form? :( If I just pass along the value that I get from the getSignatureKey method, it'll just pass it as "byte[] array" string.. not the actual key itself? o.O

Comment: It looks like AWS wants the signature as a hex digest. In C#, you can get that via `String.Concat(bytes.Select(b => b.ToString("X2")).ToArray())`. Not sure if it matters or not, but the AWS example signature is all lowercase, so you may need to call `ToLower` on that as well.

Answer (score 1):

```
/*

    DOCUMENTATION: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/latest/DG/rest-signature.html#rest_detailedexample
*/

    var itemID = "0679722769";
    var accessKeyID = "AKIAIOSFODNN7EXAMPLE";
    var timeStamp = DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("o");
    var req = $"Service=AWSECommerceService&AWSAccessKeyId={accessKeyID}&Operation=ItemLookup&IdType=UPC&ItemId={itemID}&Version=2013-08-01&Timestamp={timeStamp}";
    req = req.Replace(":", "%3A").Replace(",", "%2C"); //UrlDecode certain characters
    var reqlist = req.Split('&').ToArray(); //we need to sort our key/value pairs
    Array.Sort(reqlist);
    req = String.Join("&", reqlist); //join everything back
    var reqToSign = $@"GET
webservices.amazon.com
/onca/xml
{req}".Replace("\r", ""); //create the request for signing. We need to replace microsofts's crlf with just a lf; Make sure there are no leading spaces after the linefeeds.

    var signage = getSignatureKey("1234567890",reqToSign);
    req = $"http://webservices.amazon.com/onca/xml?{req}&Signature={signage}"; //create our request with the signature appended.
    return req;
}

private static byte[] HmacSHA256(String data, byte[] key)
{
    String algorithm = "HmacSHA256";
    KeyedHashAlgorithm kha = KeyedHashAlgorithm.Create(algorithm);
    kha.Key = key;

    return kha.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data));
}


private static string getSignatureKey(string key, string stringToSign)
{
    byte[] kSecret = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(key.ToCharArray());
    byte[] kSigning = HmacSHA256(stringToSign, kSecret);
    return WebUtility.UrlEncode(Convert.ToBase64String(kSigning));
}
```

Contrary to most of the answers found here and elsewhere, this is the only way that works. The entire request has to be hashed, not just particular parameters. I can't speak to other Amazon services, but the Commerce Service has to be done like this.

Quite a few answers here and elsewhere referenced this: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/sigv4-calculate-signature.html
This is most certainly not correct. If you're not passing a region parameter, how can Amazon create the same signature since it doesn't have all the information.